# Error while adding a secondary instance in mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I am trying to deploy mongodb replica set . I have made my mongodb instance as primary of the replica . Now i am trying to add another mongodb instance hosted at different iP address, as secondary of the replica, but i am getting the following error :

```
    rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("<ip address>:27017")
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2",
    "code" : 103
}
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 8):

I face this issue when i tried to run two mongod instance in same machine. It throws error when i provide like

```
   rs.add("localhost:27027")
   (or)
   rs.add("127.0.0.1:27027")
```

where `27027` is the port number of secondary.

**Solution:**

Pass the hostname instead of ip address

```
  rs.add("myhostname:27027")
```

Comment: For me rs.add("127.0.0.1:27027") worked. Both other options rs.add("localhost:27027") and rs.add("hostname:27017") threw and error

Comment: I tried using the IP address of the machine in which all of the replica sets were hosted, 172.16.10.160,
rs.add("172.16.10.160:27018")
that worked after failing with hostname, but mainly because I set the listen address to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Does the IP address of your newly added replica set member resolve to localhost ? Or, does your already existing member resolve to localhost ? Either way, a replica set will not allow mixed localhost / non-localhost configuration.

Take a look at the [source code location](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/repl/replica_set_config.cpp#L334) of this message.

Also, the [Mongo guide on sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) says this:

> If you use either “localhost” or 127.0.0.1 as the hostname portion of
>   any host identifier, for example as the host argument to addShard or
>   the value to the --configdb run time option, then you must use
>   “localhost” or 127.0.0.1 for all host settings for any MongoDB
>   instances in the cluster. If you mix localhost addresses and remote
>   host address, MongoDB will error.

The same applies for replica sets.

Comment: Any idea on how to deal with this when trying to add a member via a ssh tunnel?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say off the bat. But in theory the tunnel should be transparent and therefore not make a difference. But you have to try it out.

Comment: The problem is that the tunnel is then accessible as "localhost:<mapped-port>", but I need to have the primary mongodb bound to 127.0.0.1 and 172.17.0.1, because containers in Docker need to access it. It is then this 172.17.0.1 which causes the trouble. Here is a better explanation https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173911/mongodb-replica-set-over-ssh-tunnels

Answer (score 0):

To reconfigure your 1-node replica set's primary from localhost / 127.0.0.1 to external hostname / ip you can do the following:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].host = "mongo0.example.net:27017"
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

First line gets current replica set configuration, second line modifies the host field of member 0, and the last one applies the new configuration.

See more details here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-hostnames-in-a-replica-set/